# PHP OOP Approach in this example

Tags: php, oop

Im working with php for about 4 years now, but i still havent really used an OOP approach on any of my own scripts. I would really like to use it though, because for waht i heard and what i understand it makes developing much easier. 
For example the following code, it is a simple mysql-select, getting categories and from the results i am building a form-element, a dropdown-menu, there are a few steps involved like fe sorting stuff with natcasesort() too. Atm i would redo the same procedure for countries, and i would write the same code again, only that categories would be replaced with country, as you can see:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * from categories WHERE hidden = 0");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) { 
    $cat_names = explode(",",$row['title_mulilingual']);
    $categories[$row['uid']] = $cat_names[$lang_id];
}

natcasesort($categories);
foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == $active_key) $selected = ' selected="selected"';
    else $item_selected = '';
    $select_fields['cat_id'] .= '<option'.$selected.' value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}   

$cat_select = '<select name="category" >'.$select_fields['cat_id'].'</select>';


// the following part is the same as the first one, it only handles countries instead of categories

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * from countries WHERE hidden = 0");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { 
    $country_names = explode(",",$row['title_mulilingual']);
    $countries[$row['uid']] = $country_names[$lang_id];
}

natcasesort($countries);
foreach ($countries as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == $active_key) $item_selected = ' selected="selected"';
    else $selected = '';
    $select_fields['country_id'] .= '<option'.$selected.' value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}   

$country_select = '<select name="country" >'.$select_fields['country_id'].'</select>';
```

So in the code it obviously is not OOP. But im guessing, that i could do this much easier by using OOP, right? Could someone help me to understand OOP better, by making this example an OOP-example?
Thanks in advance,
Jayden

Comment: "Could someone help me to understand OOP better, by making this example an OOP-example?" --- OOP **IS** a rocket science. It is not possible to get it just by examples. "it makes developing much easier" --- it assumes you know **a lot**. If you have read a lot of books related to how to design well - then it is "easy", indeed.

Comment: Have you read http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: OOP is first and foremost a manner of approach. In order to use OOP on that bit of code (and in order for it to save time rather than waste it) we would have to *approach* the whole project as an OOP project. We would emulate structures & behaviours regarding the application wide *business objects* which we then use in different contexts (thus reusing the code). What you are doing above is just one of the contexts that we would be able to use the structures & behaviours we create. If you only see a context and tens of lines of (apparently) extra code just to achieve this, it'd look wasteful

Comment: examples are good for learning :)

Comment: So is reading [OOP](php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php), as a plus... the have examples there.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2):

> Could someone help me to understand OOP better, by making this example an OOP-example?

Hey you could easily port this into OOP with a framework like MVC.

[image: MVC Structure]
<sub>(source: [php-html.net](http://php-html.net/tutorials/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/mvc-collaboration.png))</sub>

> "Model–View–Controller (MVC) is a design pattern for computer user interfaces that divides an application into three areas of responsibility:
>
> > - the Model: the domain objects or data structures that represent the application's state.
> > - The View, which observes the state and generates output to the users.
> > - The Controller, which translates user input into operations on the model." (Wikipedia, 2012)

Some really good OOP frameworks already available.

- [ash.MVC](https://web.archive.org/web/20151008015829/http://www.phpframeworks.com:80/php-frameworks/index.php?id=14)
- [cake PHP](https://web.archive.org/web/20150910123915/http://phpframeworks.com:80/php-frameworks/index.php?id=2)
- [Symfony](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006095719/http://www.phpframeworks.com:80/php-frameworks/index.php?id=3)

A good tutorial on how to create a Model View Control can be found [here](https://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/).

**Controller**

This retrieves the data and then sends it to the model to be processed.

```
 include_once("model/Model.php");

 class Controller {
 public $model; 

 public function __construct()
 {
      $this->model = new Model();
 } 

 public function invoke()
 {
      if (!isset($_GET['book']))
      {
           // no special book is requested, we'll show a list of all available books
           $books = $this->model->getBookList();
           include 'view/booklist.php';
      }
      else
      {
           // show the requested book
           $book = $this->model->getBook($_GET['book']);
           include 'view/viewbook.php';
      }
 }
 }
```

**Model**

It processes the data to be presented

```
include_once("model/Book.php");

class Model {
public function getBookList()
{
    // here goes some hardcoded values to simulate the database
    return array(
        "Jungle Book" => new Book("Jungle Book", "R. Kipling", "A classic book."),
        "Moonwalker" => new Book("Moonwalker", "J. Walker", ""),
        "PHP for Dummies" => new Book("PHP for Dummies", "Some Smart Guy", "")
    );
}

public function getBook($title)
{
    // we use the previous function to get all the books and then we return the requested one.
    // in a real life scenario this will be done through a db select command
    $allBooks = $this->getBookList();
    return $allBooks[$title];
}

}

class Book {
public $title;
public $author;
public $description;

public function __construct($title, $author, $description)
{
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->author = $author;
    $this->description = $description;
}
}
```

**View**

Presents the data.

```
<?php 

    echo 'Title:' . $book->title . '<br/>';
    echo 'Author:' . $book->author . '<br/>';
    echo 'Description:' . $book->description . '<br/>';

?>
```

from my experience I find its easier to do OOP using a framework than learning it from scratch in web applications.

Theres also a good tutorial on creating your own framework at nettuts that can be found [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-php5-framework-part-1--net-520), If you don't understand the above information this tutorial isn't to overwhelming.

Comment: that is not helpful, OOP is not MVC Framework, it just happens that MVC Frameworks are usually written in OOP.

Comment: Yeah I know. Some frameworks cache stuff as objects and then pull them from the cache instead of reinitializing new objects on each request. (Activecollab for example)

Comment: But this question is about learning OOP, not using a MVC Framework, the person wants to re-write their code as an OOP example.

Comment: "because MVC depends on the framework" this is not true, you could've written a set of model/view/controller classes without using a framework. Since it's an attempt to teach the guy OOP it would actually be more useful than reading the source code of huge (sometimes bloated) MVC frameworks that abstract 2-3 levels of logic and inheritance to obtain the flexibility they need. Offering a really simple set of model/view/controller classes would've been easier to read.